# Neo4j - Creating nodes when an intermediate one does not exist

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm using a `LOAD CSV` for some tests, and i figured out one problem. How can I create an intermediate node if there isn't one already, using a `CREATE`?

For example:

I have `(p:Person)-[:HAS_BANCOMAT]->(bm:Bancomat)-[:FROM]->(b:Bank)`. In my model, one Person can only have one bancomat, so, if in my CSV file I'm going to find some people who actually have more then one Bancomat, I will just persist the first occurrence.

I've ended up with this script:

```
LOAD CSV FROM 'file:///myfile.csv' as row
WITH row.name as name, row.bank as bank, row.id as bancomat_id
//OMITTING CREATING PERSONS p AND BANKS b PART
//JUST GOING ON WHAT IS NOT WORKING
WHERE size((p)-[:HAS_BANCOMAT]->(:Bancomat)-[:FROM]->(b)) = 0
CREATE (bm:Bancomat {bancomatId: row.bancomat_id})
CREATE (p)-[:HAS_BANCOMAT]->(bm)
CREATE (bm)-[:FROM]->(b)
```

The size part it's not working. I've also tried using `NOT` over the `(p)-[:HAS_BANCOMAT]->(:Bancomat)-[:FROM]->(b)` path, bot it doesn't work either.

`MERGE` is not the solution I'm looking for.

Any suggestions about what I'm doing wrong?

EDIT1: it's not working because this script will create anyway more then one linked Bancomat if some persons got more then one.

Comment: Why do you say that `MERGE` is not the solution? `MERGE (p)-[:HAS_BANCOMAT]->(bm:Bancomat {bancomatId: row.bancomat_id})` should give you what you want.

Comment: @kamaugh: It is not clear what you want to do. Do you want to end up with all `p` nodes (found from the input file) having only a single `HAS_BANCOMAT` relationship to a `Bancomat`, with that `Bancomat` having the expected `bancomat_id` (and a `FROM` relationship to the found `b` node)?